# The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object context

Tags: c#, nhibernate

im trying to update a record in the database and it errors, i know the entry is there

```
            Order od = null;
            od = _session.Single<Order>(x => x.OrderId == OrderId);
            if (od != null)
            {
                od.PricePaid = svm.price;
                _session.Update(od);
                _session.CommitChanges();
```

but im getting

> The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object
>   context. An object can only be reattached when it is in an unchanged
>   state.

Help please :)

Comment: Neither `Single` nor `CommitChanges` are methods of NHibernate's Session. We'll be able to help you better if you show all the relevant code and/or remove wrappers that might be buggy.

Answer (score 1):

Ommit `_session.Update(od)` part of your code, it should work.